# postgresql move database to another server

Tags: database, postgresql, move, psql

I am trying to migrate a database from one server to another with this command (psql 9.5):

```
pg_dump -C -h localhost -p 1331 -U postgres Station_list | psql -h 192.168.1.207 -p 1332 -U postgres Station_list2
```

But nothing happens, the database is not copied.

Comment: This is mine:sudo -u postgres /opt/pkgs/postgresql-9.3/bin/pg_dumpall -p 5432 -U postgres | sudo -u postgres /opt/pkgs/postgresql-9.3.4/bin/psql -p 5433 -U postgres,

Comment: why -C option in your command?

Comment: i use Win OS, -C it my mistake) Try
`pg_dump -h localhost -p 1331 -U postgres Station_list | psql -h 192.168.1.207 -p 1332 -U postgres Station_list2` also does not work

Comment: No other error information?

Comment: No, I enter command and have no results